# Installing multiple versions of software with git

Tags: c++, git

I'm really struggling to understand `git`, so here's a tighter rephrasing of a previous question I had asked. I'm going to explain a hypothetical scenario, detailing what I think happens when you download some code using `git` and install it on a machine, and hopefully somebody can tell me which part I am incorrect about!

1. I run `git clone git://github.com/foo/foo.git`
2. This creates a local directory `foo`, and downloads the source code and git data
3. This source code effectively contains all the versions of the software: source files, header file, and git data for the different versions
4. I run `git checkout release-1.0`
5. This tells my system that I want to deal with version 1.0 of the software
6. I run `make`, which compiles the code for version 1.0
7. This creates a library called `libfoo.so.1`
8. I run `make install`, which installs the library
9. This copies over `libfoo.so.1` into the directory `/usr/local/lib`
10. It also copies over the header file `foo.h` into the directory `/usr/local/include`
11. This header file is the version of `foo.h` that corresponds to version 1.0 of the software
12. I now also want to install version 2 of the software, so I run `git checkout release-2.0`
13. This tells my system that I want to deal with version 2.0 of the software
14. I run `make`, which compiles the code for version 2.0
15. This creates a library called `libfoo.so.2`
16. I run `make install`, which installs the library
17. This copies over `libfoo.so.2` into the directory `/usr/local/lib`
18. It also copies over the header file `foo.h` into the directory `/usr/local/include`
19. This header file is the version of `foo.h` that corresponds to version 2.0 of the software
20. I now try to create a project which depends on version 2.0 of the software, and link it to `libfoo.so.2` which is at `/usr/local/lib`, and include `foo.h` which is at `/usr/local/include`
21. This project compiles and runs fine
22. I now try to create a project which depends on version 1.0 of the software, and link it to `libfoo.so.1` which is at `/usr/local/lib`, and include `foo.h` which is at `/usr/local/include`
23. This project does not compile ok, because `foo.h` is the header file for version 2.0 of the software, not version 1.0.

So, the thing I am puzzled about is how you can have two versions of some software installed on your machine. The actual library files `libfoo.so.1` and `libfoo.so.2` are both created and can be linked to by two different projects, but there is only one version of `foo.h` installed on the local machine. Therefore, only the version which was installed the latest will have the correct header file, because the two versions require different versions of `foo.h`.

Please can somebody explain where I am getting confused? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a git problem at all. In fact, it has nothing to do with Git or even a program you're trying to install. It's just a version conflict.

To solve this type of problems, there are many possible approaches:

- Installing each version in a separate virtual machine
- ... in a separate [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers
- Using smart package managers like [nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) which would allow you to have any number of versions of a same program installed
- probably something else...

In cases like this, I prefer use Docker since its' containers are lightweight (compared to virtual machines). This way, I can have any kind of environment to build and run any program. Any dependencies are installed directly in a container, so when I run my build against it, everything is already there, and my host machine is not polluted with random software.

---

Regarding to your approach with Git. You're doing it right, but it would work anyway exactly because you can't have two versions of a same header file simultaneously. You seem to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding (and correct me if I am wrong - sorry for the recursion):

3. No, only for the current branch
4. Selects branch

Git is tree-like in nature, but the main purpose is to progress back to the Master - which is the trunk of the tree.

What is likely happening is that you overwrite the local files when running make. [Read more here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).